# Viewing Twitter replies

Tags: twitter

I am having a recent problem on Twitter. I used to be able to see replies to a person's tweet by just clicking on the reply arrow. It would show all the replies that people have done to this tweet. But in the last few days when I do this, it just opens up a dialogue box. I don't know what I did to change my settings. This has happened to me before and it eventually got fixed. I checked on Firefox and Google Chrome and they are both doing the same thing. So I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: What does the dialog box say?

Comment: I believe the other person who replied got it for me. I could have swore that I hit the reply button to see other replies, but you have hit the tweet itself to see them. That's my bad. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: @EricS: If my answer helped you. You can accept that, so this question can be close as solved.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with Twitter reply, it is doing same what it has to do. I think you are confuse.

When you click on reply arrow, it open a box (with the person's Twitter handle who has tweet) to write your reply. If someone has re-twetted it their handle also will be there in the box.

To see the all the replies click on the tweet, not on reply arrow.

Comment: It is interesting. It looks like you are correct. I've been on twitter for 6 yrs and i could have swore I hit the reply button to see the other replies. Maybe old age is catching up to me. Ha. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You know what. I'll add another comment. I actually think I am correct. It's got to be something to do with my settings. My computer was worked on recently and that may have screwed things up. But I think I am correct in saying that I could see replies by clicking on the reply button. I am not dreaming that. But it is all cool. I will just do it this different way. I like my old way better.